# Passing ID to URL, ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass an id to the URL, However I cant hard code the ID but I need to pass the id from the model.

It is basically a collection of a particular type of model displayed as a table.
When the user clicks on the id value of the table i need to be able to pass the id to the URL so that it can open a corresponding detailed page of the same.

```
<a href="~/Instance/Details/id=@Url.Encode(modelitem => item.Id)">   @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Id)</a>
```

This is what I am trying, need help:).

Comment: `modelitem => item.Id` this looks wrong. Shouldn't it be `modelitem => modelitem.Id`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, use the `Url.Action` method to generate the correct relative url to the action method.

```
@foreach (var item in SomeCollection)
{
  <div>
       <a href="@Url.Action("Details","Instance",new { id = item.Id })"> 
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Id)
       </a>
  </div>
}
```

The `Url.Action` method will generate the url value to details action method, which includes the `item.Id` value in the url.

Assuming `Instance` is the controller name where your `Details` action method is present with `id` parameter.

```
public class InstanceController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Details(int id)
   {
      return Content("Details of "+id);
      // to do : return a view with data queried using id
   }
}
```

Comment: `new { id = item.Id }` should probably be `new { id = Model.Id }`

Comment: @LewsTherin He is doing it inside a collection. So it should be the item he is loop is currently executing, which is `item.Id`.

Comment: @Sam Axe I updated your edit. Since it is a loop, it should be `modelitem => item.Id`. If you use `modelitem => modelitem .Id`, it is not valid. You will get an error from razor.

Comment: Oh okay, I missed that. Thanks for updating your answer.

Comment: `modelitem => item.Id` still doesn't make any sense to me. The input variable `modelitem` isn't used in that lambda expression. Shouldn't it still be `modelitem => modelitem.Id`? Won't `item` be passed in to the `modelitem` input parameter when the lambda expression is evaluated?

Comment: @LewsTherin You will get this error : **The type arguments for method 'DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor<TModel, TValue>(HtmlHelper<TModel>, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.**